# Deleted /boot and removed kernel

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, dpkg

I happen to have deleted the `/boot` directory on my system instead of on the one I was supposed to.. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/711803/425454) in order to restore it, however I had problems with `apt --reinstall` so I decided to remove and install the packages manually. Probably not the brightest idea, now have 2 broken images that I do not know how to fix.

Running `dpkg --audit` tells me

```
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic Signed kernel image generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic Signed kernel image generic
```

Running `dpkg --configure linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic`

```
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic (4.15.0-42.45) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic (4.15.0-42.45) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic
```

However `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms` exists

```
~$ ls -l /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1120 авг 31  2016 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms
```

My machine is still running though, is it possible to save it?

EDIT:

Just tried to run `dkms` manually and found out `/bin/bash` was missing. Installed it with `apt install bash` and then issued the commands

```
dpkg --audit
apt install -f
update-grub
```

Everything looks normal now, however after reboot there is no ubuntu boot option in grub..

Answer (score 1):

- Boot with a Live Ubuntu Disc
- Mount the partition/s with Ubuntu file system, on /mnt
- Example

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdxx /mnt
  sudo mount /dev/sdxy /mnt/boot
  sudo mount /dev/sdxz /mnt/boot/efi
  ```

  Where sdx=disk, sdxx="/" partition, sdxy="boot" partition,sdxz="efi" partition

  then run

  ```
  for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
  sudo chroot mnt
  ```
- **Most importantly**, since you have lost your /boot/grub/efi and may be /boot/grub/efi  also.

  - Find your boot type

    ```
    [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"
    ```
  - If internet problem.

    ```
    echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >/etc/resolv.conf
    ```

    or

    ```
    cp /mnt/etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
    ```
  - For legacy/bios boot

    ```
    apt install --reinstall grub-pc grub-common
    ```
  - For UEFI(efi) boot

    ```
    apt install --reinstall grub-common grub-efi grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin
    ```
  - And

    ```
    grub-install /sdx # no apt infront
    ```
  - Now run

    ```
    dpkg -S /boot
    sudo dpkg --audit
    ```

to find the packages needed. Install the packages.

- Then

  ```
  apt --fix-missing install
  update-initramfs -u 
  update-grub
  ```

  and

  ```
  exit
  for i in /sys /proc /dev/pts /dev; do sudo umount /mnt$i; done
  ```

  Unmount mounted partitions.

  Example:

  ```
  sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi
  sudo umount /mnt/boot
  sudo umount /mnt
  sudo reboot
  ```
- For errors after rebooting.

  ```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  ```

Comment: I just did all that, all commands run fine, apt doesn't report any errors, says images are installed - everything looks good, except when I reboot there is only windows and system setup (bios) in grub..

Comment: also when reinstalling the images I see it says it's adding boot menu entry for windows boot manager and efi firmware configuration, not sure if there should be such message for grub which is missing?

`grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdc1.  Check your device.map.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration` where `/dev/sdc1` is my ubutnu live flash drive

Comment: @php_nub_qq seethe edited answer. I see that you have efi boot.

Comment: Ok we're certainly going somewhere. I am now seeing ubuntu and advanced options for ubuntu in grub, however when I chose to boot in ubuntu it takes unusually long and then flashes a console screen with a message of some files being checked or something and then a bunch of lines saying something about a key that is not trusted, I can only provide so much information because the screen flashes for probably less than a second. After this a terminal appears as if I'm running a server version of ubuntu which I'm not, and I can't login because any input from the keyboard appears to be ignored -->

Comment: Which is also the case when going in recovery mode, keyboard is not working but it works in grub menu.

Comment: @php_nub_qq thanks for edit. Why not try `fsck` and `apt install -f` from Ubuntu live DVD/USB drive.

Comment: Do you mean while chrooted in the mounted broken system? Sorry if it's a dumb question, I only have basic knowledge, `apt install -f` just says there is 0 packages to be updated or installed and I'm not familiar with `fsck`

Comment: You are right. `fsck` before mount and `apt install -f` after chroot. (Writing from mobile)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88197/discussion-between-php-nub-qq-and-vijay).