# Accidentally deleted bootloader partition

Tags: grub2, bootloader, boot-partition

I have a system with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (only).

I have accidentally deleted the small 512MB partition which contained the bootloader (thinking I was modifying a USB drive - oops). Now it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBmNN.png

While the system was still running I created a Ubuntu 20.04.1 USB. After restarting, the system would not load so I booted from the USB and ran Ubuntu from there. I ran something called boot-repair which printed this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Gp2Q5ZZ7jk/

I don't know what a lot of that means. Please send help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleted /boot and removed kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109115/deleted-boot-and-removed-kernel)

Comment: I managed to solve it using boot-repair. The trick was to use gparted to create a FAT32 partition in the place where I'd deleted it, then right-click on the partition and select flags: boot,eps. Then run boot-repair. It ended with an error, saying that errors occurred and providing a pastebin link. For whatever reason, this was enough to allow my system to boot when I restarted it. So uh, black magic. I have no idea what I just did but it works now. Hooray?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: From that link: "I've seen various instructions for replacing GRUB by mucking around with GRUB commands or some such, but to me the easiest way is to simply chroot into your install and run update-grub." Nope, that didn't work, the grub install/update commands gave a variety of errors. Doesn't matter, I "fixed" it as described above and it all seems to work now.